# Pandas Even Wider Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, wide-format-data

I'm looking to make data even wider than what pd.pivot can provide, and am looking to even change the names of the columns to fit my needs.

I have 3 items with 3 stats that perform differently in 2 regions:

```
na = pd.DataFrame({
    'item':['a','b','c'],
    'stat1':[3,9,4],
    'stat2':[84,23,55],
    'stat3':[131,293,201]
})
''' na dataframe
  item  stat1  stat2  stat3
0    a      3     84    131
1    b      9     23    293
2    c      4     55    201
'''

eu = pd.DataFrame({
    'item':['a','b','c'],
    'stat1':[5,1,7],
    'stat2':[34,61,29],
    'stat3':[839,531,339]
})
''' eu dataframe
  item  stat1  stat2  stat3
0    a      5     34    839
1    b      1     61    531
2    c      7     29    339
'''
```

I am hoping to reshape them in a way to have all my stats per region on one line:

```
final = pd.DataFrame({
    'region': ['na','eu'],
    'a.stat1': [3,5],
    'a.stat2': [84,34],
    'a.stat3': [131,839],
    'b.stat1': [9,1],
    'b.stat2': [23,61],
    'b.stat3': [293,531],
    'c.stat1': [4,7],
    'c.stat2': [55,29],
    'c.stat3': [201,339]
})
''' resultant dataframe
  region  a.stat1  a.stat2  a.stat3  b.stat1  b.stat2  b.stat3  c.stat1  c.stat2  c.stat3
0     na        3       84      131        9       23      293        4       55      201
1     eu        5       34      839        1       61      531        7       29      339
'''
```

It seems like this is not possible using pd.pivot/pivot_table? How might I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mapping of dataframe `name` -> `value` pairs. Assign the `name` column then `concat` all the dataframes. Then `pivot` to reshape and optionally flatten the multiindex columns

```
d = {'na': na, 'eu': eu}
out = pd.concat({k: v.assign(name=k) for k, v in d.items()})
out = out.pivot(index='name', columns='item')
out.columns = out.columns.map('{0[1]}.{0[0]}'.format)
```

---

```
    a.stat1  b.stat1  c.stat1  a.stat2  b.stat2  c.stat2  a.stat3  b.stat3  c.stat3
na        3        9        4       84       23       55      131      293      201
eu        5        1        7       34       61       29      839      531      339
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the transformations before and after the pivot to make pivot work!

Comment: @ZtoYi happy coding!